# How to create fragments with newInstance() when using NavController?

Tags: android, android-navigation

I'm creating a single-activity app  that uses `NavController` and fragments to display each screen.

The app has a home screen and contains three other menu items in the nav drawer so the user can visit different websites in an external browser.

In the `onCreate()` method of my `MainActivity`, I have:

```
mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
// Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each menu should be considered as top level destinations.
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
        R.id.nav_home,
        R.id.nav_visit_website_1,
        R.id.nav_visit_website_2,
        R.id.nav_visit_website_3)
        .setDrawerLayout(mDrawerLayout)
        .build();
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

I've created a `VisitWebsiteFragment` class which has a static `newInstance(String websiteUrl)` method - with the intention of using it for the three website menu items.

I've read through the [navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation), but I'm not sure how to intercept/control the NavController in order to create the three fragment instances with `VisitWebsiteFragment.newInstance(...)`.

There may be some aspect of navigation that I'm totally missing. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you looking for how to pass data between destination?

Comment: AFAIK, what you want isn't supported directly. You could use the safe-args plugin and generated classes to pass the string, instead of via the factory method.

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi Yes, really I am wanting to pass a url String to my VisitWebsiteFragment.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. I just stumbled across something which may be quite close to Safe Args (which I've just added as an answer). I'll check it out properly, though.

Comment: All Safe Args does is code-generate code for the sender and recipient to package those arguments up in a type-safe fashion. Either way (plain arguments like in your answer or augmented by Safe Args) works.

Answer (score 2):

The IDs of the menu items are `nav_visit_website_1`, `nav_visit_website_2` and `nav_visit_website_3`.

Adding this code to my **nav_graph.xml** gives me what I need:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/visit_website"
    android:name="org.example.VisitWebsiteFragment"
    android:label="@string/visit_website" />

<action
    android:id="@+id/nav_visit_website_1"
    app:destination="@id/visit_website">
    <argument
        android:name="url"
        app:argType="string"
        android:defaultValue="https://example.com/website1" />
</action>

<action
    android:id="@+id/nav_visit_website_2"
    app:destination="@id/visit_website">
    <argument
        android:name="url"
        app:argType="string"
        android:defaultValue="https://example.com/website2" />
</action>

<action
    android:id="@+id/nav_visit_website_3"
    app:destination="@id/visit_website">
    <argument
        android:name="url"
        app:argType="string"
        android:defaultValue="https://example.com/website3" />
</action>
```

Comment: Hi, I just encountered a similar problem. My Fragment contains a companion object and is accepting a string argument. However the error (could not find fragment constructor) keep coming up even if I followed your answer, do you have any ideas? thank you very much!

Comment: @matthewhang Sorry, no other ideas. You might be best posting your issue as a new question. (If you do, it may be worth mentioning this question/answer.)